# Dynamically insert values extracted from a string to a table with multiple instances

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently faced with the following conundrum.

I need to convert this:

```
@string = 'TM_15 <= 0.574803 AND TM_3 <= 0.4 AND TM_9 <= 0.298738 AND TM_8 <= 0.30605 
AND TM_16 <= 0.367816 AND TM_12 <= 0.341463 AND TM_10 <= 0.379487 AND TM_4 <= 0.44186 
AND TM_2 <= 0.45 AND TM_7 <= 0.247525 AND TM_1 <= 0.6 AND TM_13 <= 0.28 AND TM_5 <= 0.285714 
AND TM_11 <= 0.6 AND TM_6 <= 0.448276 AND TM_15 <= 0.285047 AND TM_14 <= 0.6 
AND TM_12 <= 0.248366 AND TM_5 <= 0.245399 AND TM_16 <= 0.09375 AND TM_3 <= 0.372093 
AND TM_15 <= 0.199713 AND TM_10 <= 0.326996 AND TM_9 <= 0.248731 AND TM_8 <= 0.279412 
AND TM_13 <= 0.248577 AND TM_4 <= 0.311475 AND TM_2 <= 0.145833 AND TM_7 <= 0.213483 
AND TM_11 <= 0.199029 AND TM_4 <= 0.165289'
```

into something that resembles this:

```
TM_0    TM_1        TM_2        TM_3        TM_4        TM_5    ... and on to 16
        <= 0.6      <= 0.45     <= 0.4      <= 0.44186  <= 0.285714 
                    <= 0.145833 <= 0.372093 <= 0.311475 <= 0.245399 
                                            <= 0.165289
```

I've managed to strip out the values into their respective columns and values. I just cant seem to insert into a table/table variable where it will be as small as possible. I dont want to land up having a massive table with over 30 entries for one string. Ideally for the example string value above there should ve a max table column count of 17 and a row count of 4. where the left over space is either null or blank.

reason being after that is done the column will be reduced to the smallest value present.

please post any suggestions or ideas.

thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Please tag the correct database in use MySQL is not the same as SQL-server.. Don't understand the output there are zero TM_1 in the string but two TM_1 in the result, there are two TM_2 in the string and three TM_2 in the output....

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your quick reply. Sorry about the tag, this is my first question on Stack. It will pertain to Sql-sever. with regards to the string vs output i see the formatting of the page has moved them around slightly. Im looking to achieve that general output though. 
So in general for a "TM_0-16" column there may be multiple values assigned. Im struggling getting them into a table with that kind of format.

Comment: What a totally bizarre request. Why do you have your data in a string like this? And how does turning this into a table make it better? It looks like a really long where predicate to me. In order to do this you will need a string splitter. You will first to split on the word AND, then split that result on <=. This is not going to perform well if you have a lot of these. Here are some great options for string splitters. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no idea why you are doing this, but you can get the output in your question using the string splitting function of you choice as mentioned in the comments by Sean Lange and a `pivot`, from which you can `insert` into a table etc:

```
declare @string nvarchar(1000) = 'TM_15 <= 0.574803 AND TM_3 <= 0.4 AND TM_9 <= 0.298738 AND TM_8 <= 0.30605 
AND TM_16 <= 0.367816 AND TM_12 <= 0.341463 AND TM_10 <= 0.379487 AND TM_4 <= 0.44186 
AND TM_2 <= 0.45 AND TM_7 <= 0.247525 AND TM_1 <= 0.6 AND TM_13 <= 0.28 AND TM_5 <= 0.285714 
AND TM_11 <= 0.6 AND TM_6 <= 0.448276 AND TM_15 <= 0.285047 AND TM_14 <= 0.6 
AND TM_12 <= 0.248366 AND TM_5 <= 0.245399 AND TM_16 <= 0.09375 AND TM_3 <= 0.372093 
AND TM_15 <= 0.199713 AND TM_10 <= 0.326996 AND TM_9 <= 0.248731 AND TM_8 <= 0.279412 
AND TM_13 <= 0.248577 AND TM_4 <= 0.311475 AND TM_2 <= 0.145833 AND TM_7 <= 0.213483 
AND TM_11 <= 0.199029 AND TM_4 <= 0.165289'

select r
      ,[TM_0]
      ,[TM_1]
      ,[TM_2]
      ,[TM_3]
      ,[TM_4]
      ,[TM_5]
      ,[TM_6]
      ,[TM_7]
      ,[TM_8]
      ,[TM_9]
      ,[TM_10]
      ,[TM_11]
      ,[TM_12]
      ,[TM_13]
      ,[TM_14]
      ,[TM_15]
      ,[TM_16]
from (
    select row_number() over (partition by left(s.item,charindex(' ',s.item,1)-1) order by s.rn) as r
          ,left(s.item,charindex(' ',s.item,1)-1) as c
          ,substring(s.item,charindex(' ',s.item,1)+1,9999) as v
    from dbo.fn_StringSplitMax(@string,'and ',null) as s
    ) as s
pivot (max(s.v) for c in([TM_0]
                        ,[TM_1]
                        ,[TM_2]
                        ,[TM_3]
                        ,[TM_4]
                        ,[TM_5]
                        ,[TM_6]
                        ,[TM_7]
                        ,[TM_8]
                        ,[TM_9]
                        ,[TM_10]
                        ,[TM_11]
                        ,[TM_12]
                        ,[TM_13]
                        ,[TM_14]
                        ,[TM_15]
                        ,[TM_16]
                        )
      ) as p
order by r
```

Output:

```
+---+------+---------+--------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| r | TM_0 |  TM_1   |     TM_2     |      TM_3      |     TM_4      |      TM_5      |     TM_6     |      TM_7      |      TM_8      |     TM_9     |    TM_10     |    TM_11     |    TM_12     |    TM_13     |   TM_14   |    TM_15     |    TM_16     |
+---+------+---------+--------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1 | NULL | <= 0.6  | <= 0.45      | <= 0.4         | <= 0.44186    | <= 0.285714    | <= 0.448276  | <= 0.247525    | <= 0.30605     | <= 0.298738  | <= 0.379487  | <= 0.6       | <= 0.341463  | <= 0.28      | <= 0.6    | <= 0.574803  | <= 0.367816  |
| 2 | NULL | NULL    | <= 0.145833  | <= 0.372093    | <= 0.311475   | <= 0.245399    | NULL         | <= 0.213483    | <= 0.279412    | <= 0.248731  | <= 0.326996  | <= 0.199029  | <= 0.248366  | <= 0.248577  | NULL      | <= 0.285047  | <= 0.09375   |
| 3 | NULL | NULL    | NULL         | NULL           | <= 0.165289   | NULL           | NULL         | NULL           | NULL           | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL         | NULL      | <= 0.199713  | NULL         |
+---+------+---------+--------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

---

String split function:

```
create function [dbo].[fn_StringSplitMax]
(
 @str nvarchar(max) = ' '           -- String to split.
,@delimiter as nvarchar(max) = ','  -- Delimiting value to split on.  Can be multiple characters.
,@num as int = null                 -- nth value will be returned.  NULL returns all.
)
returns table
as
return
    with s as
    (       -- Convert the string to an XML value, replacing the delimiter with XML tags
        select convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((select @str for xml path('')),@delimiter,'</x><x>') + '</x>').query('.') as s
    )
    select rn
          ,item     -- Select the values from the generated XML value by CROSS APPLYing to the XML nodes
    from(select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn
               ,n.x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as item
         from s
             cross apply s.nodes('x') as n(x)
        ) a
    where rn = @num
       or @num is null;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what im looking for. I know its not ideal, but unfortunately that is the issue that im tasked with. can i ask which string splitting function you used?.

Comment: @Marc  Updated my answer to include.